# FullCalendar no muestra correctamente la fecha 'end'

Tags: php, laravel, date, fullcalendar

Yo tengo mi lista de eventos, los cuales tienen una fecha de inicio y final (con formato YYYY-MM-DD). Dichos eventos se visualizan en el calendario de FullCalendar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo las fechas no se muestran en su totalidad, si no que la fecha de fin de cada evento no toma el ultimo dia, por ejemplo, el evento "CUMPLEAÑOS" (el verde) tiene una duracion desde el **Miercoles 1** hasta el **Sabado 4**, sin embargo el Sabado 4 no lo incluye. Lo que estoy buscando es que se incluyan dichas fechas de los eventos, algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el javascript que muestra el evento en el calendario:

```js
    $(document).ready(function()
     {
        // page is now ready, initialize the calendar...
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar(
        {
            locale: 'es',
            header:
            {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: false,
            events: [
            @foreach($eventos as $evento)
            {
                title: "{!! $evento->Nombre !!}",
                start: "{!! $evento->FechaDesde !!}",
                end: "{!! $evento->FechaHasta !!}",
                url: "{!! url("abm_acciones/mostrarevento/".$evento->CD_Evento) !!}",
                allDay: true
            },
            @endforeach
            ]
        });
    });
```

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Código?, sino no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: @GabrielJeremyRodriguezRiver No se cual es la necesidad de mostrar el código si solo es un tema de fechas, pero ahí te deje el javascript que inserta los eventos en el calendario.

Comment: Por que es un código lo que se corregirá y no una imagen.

Comment: Coloca ejemplo de las fechas que traes de la db para ver que estas insertando.

Answer (score 3):

El plugin esta interpretando bien la duración de las fechas inicia el miércoles 1 a las 0 hrs y termina el sábado 4 a las 0 hrs.

Ahora si tu le pasas una fecha de esta manera `2017/01/01` el plugin le agregara las horas dejando la fecha de esta manera `2017/01/01 00:00:00`, si lo que quieres es que también ocupe el día final de la fecha `end` deja la fecha en este formato `2017/01/04 23:59:59` así ocupara todo el día.

Comment: interesante, no tengo ese problema por que yo lo manejo con hora inicio y hora final. Bien.

Comment: @PabloContreras aveces también sucede con horas, no se si también tenga algo que ver con la zona horaria, pero muchas veces yo he usado esto `2017/01/04 04:00:00` y no se pinta el día Sábado, pero si pongo `2017/01/04 09:00:00` ya me aparece pintado, por eso menciono lo de la zona horaria.

Comment: entonces es un plugin que hay que estudiar bien a fondo, a lo que yo necesito (actualmente) no me ha dado problemas, pero ya con esto que dices me das ideas para un futuro.

Answer (score 0):

a mi me funciono añadir +'T12:30:00', de esta manera indicaba que el ultimo día acababa en esa determinada hora.
Con un combo, quedaria asi: end: $("#datFin").val()+'T12:30:00',

Answer (score -1):

amigos, como haria para poder activar siempre la Fecha Actual en el FullCalendar ya que aparece es una fecha predefinida

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2017-10-09',
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {

            $('#ModalAdd #start').val(moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd #end').val(moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'));
            $('#ModalAdd').modal('show');
        },
```

me gustaria que apareciera la del PC

y otra duda es, los valores de los Dias y Meses aparecen en ingles, donde puedo editarlos para ponerlos en español, incluso los de los botones (Hoy, Semana, Mes y Dia) del menu u opciones del menu del Fullcalendar

Comment: Hola Gerardo, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Las respuestas no deberían usarse para realizar nuevas preguntas. Si tienes una duda, crea tu propia pregunta (siempre puedes añadir un enlace a ésta como referencia). Te recomiendo que leas [ask] y [answer], y que completes el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Comment: hola , modificando el valor defaultDate: '2017-10-09',
cuyo valor default(predefinido) es igual a esa fecha, 
para asignarle la fecha de tu computador coloca esto despues de defaultDate:
      moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');